# Hypernym for pencil, pen, marker, crayon, paint brush, etc?

Tags: hypernyms

I'm writing rules for a board game. It's similar to dots and boxes, and I would like to have a nice general word or phrase to refer to what the players use to mark their moves on the board or paper, since one could conceivably use anything to do it, like a pen, pencil, crayon or even a paint brush if they wanted to use one.

The best I could think of was drawing implement, but that sounds too technical, and I'm trying to shoot for the lowest reading level I can.

I also thought about drawing tool, marking tool or maybe even just marker? What do you think?

Comment: Do you need to refer to the writing tool? How about just telling the players to *write* their moves?

Comment: Not sure why you need to refer to the implement.  Seems like you're deliberately painting yourself into a corner.  They might want to scratch their skin until it bleeds, and write with blood using their pinky finger.

Answer (score 10):

*Writing instrument*, *writing utensil*, and *writing implement* are all rather common. They are not old-fashioned.

I think all of these are better than *marker*, which is standardly used only in the restricted sense referring to sharpies, felt pens, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just try [marker](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marker) - something used for marking.

A marker can be anything that leaves a mark or anything used to mark. 
Avoid using a sesquipedalian word.

Comment: I'm sure no one would do that as *sesquipedalian* is an adjective, not a countable noun.

Comment: @WS2 oh my. I almost forgot. :)

Answer (score 0):

**stylus**  any of various pointed, pen-shaped instruments used in drawing, artwork, etc.

[second definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stylus)